# Integration of a function with a radical using trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I can't seem to figure this one out:

$\int \frac{t^5}{\sqrt{t^2+2}}dt$

$t^5 / \sqrt{t^2+2}$

I know I need to substitute t for a trigonometric function, $\tan$ I think

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$I_n=\int \frac{t^n}{\sqrt{t^2+a^2}} dt$$ Put $t=a\tan u$ to get $$I_n=a^{n}\int {\tan^nu}\ {\sec u du}$$ If $n$ is odd then, by replacing $\sec u=z$ you will get $$I_n=a^n\int (z^2-1)^{n/2}dz$$ which you can then expand and integrate.

If $n$ is even then by integration by parts $$I_n=\tan^{n-1}u\sec u-(n-1)\int \tan ^{n-2}u \sec^3u\  du=\tan^{n-1}u\sec u-(n-1)I_{n-2}-(n-1)I_{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you don't necessarily need trigonometric substitution to solve this problem.

Substituting $u=t^2+2$,

$$\int \frac{t^5}{\sqrt{t^2+2}} dt = \int \frac{(u-2)^2}{2\sqrt{u}}du\\
=\int\frac12u^{3/2}du-\int 2\sqrt{u}\,du+\int\frac{2}{\sqrt{u}}du\\
=\frac15u^{5/2}-\frac43 u^{3/2}+4\sqrt{u}+constant\\
=\frac15(t^2+2)^{5/2}-\frac43 (t^2+2)^{3/2}+4\sqrt{t^2+2}+constant$$

---

Notes:

Let $u=t^2+2$. Then,

$$t^2=u-2\implies t^4=(t^2)^2=(u-2)^2.$$

From $u=t^2+2$, we also have $du=2t\,dt\implies \frac12du=t\,dt$. Hence,

$$t^5dt=(t^4)\cdot(t\,dt)=\frac{(u-2)^2}{2}du$$

Comment: I don't follow the first line, where does $(u-2)^2$ come from?

Comment: @JeremiahBarrar See edit for a walkthrough of the algebra.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer, it is insightful